# Import txt file to Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, import, load-data-infile

I have a problem and would like to know if anybody can help me..

I have a text file containing data separated by "," and I have a table where I need to import them into. Here is what I have so far.

This is my contact.php file

```
<?php

$dbH = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect to MySQL server.<br>' . mysql_error()); 


mysql_select_db('test') or die('Could not select database.<br>' . mysql_error(); 


$CSVFile = 'import.txt';


mysql_query('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "import.txt" INTO TABLE wp_contact_employees FIELDS TERMINATED BY "," LINES TERMINATED BY "\r\n";') or die('Error loading data file.<br>' . mysql_error());


mysql_close($dbH);
?>
```

this is my import.txt file..

```
kagn@test.com, Kralle G, 99998888 \\n
many@test.com, Martin N, 99876543 \\n
```

And in my "wp_contact_employees" I want the above to be inserted in (mail, name, tel) column.

Im new to all this php, and im stuck now :(

Comment: What kind of error message are you getting from MySQL ?

Comment: You should use PDO or mysqli instead of the deprecated 'mysql' functions.  'mysql' has been deprecated and is very susceptible to attack.

Comment: Shouldn't it rather be `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ", "`? And what's the problem with your code? Is the import.txt file not in the right directory for mysql?

Comment: im getting this error: 

    Error loading data file.
    File 'import.txt' not found (Errcode: 2)


I have created a folder on my ftp, where i have placed both the .php file and .txt file, and open the .php file on my browser, and getting the error..

Answer (score 0):

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` requires that the file pathname you specify be visible to the `mysqld` server process. Your server is on localhost, so that means MySQL is running on the same machine as your php. That's a good start.

Now you need to figure out the full pathname for your `import.txt` file. This depends on how your server is set up, but it may be something like

```
 /home/user3433414/public_ftp/data/import.txt
```

Once you have that working, you may need to change the protection of your .txt file so it is readable by the `world.`

It's unfortunately impossible to tell you in detail what to do without knowing the ins and outs of your hosting provider's server setup.  Perhaps you should ask for help from their support team.

Comment: Hey Ollie, my pathname is E:\inetpub\gajan\kontaktdb\import.txt, but still giving me the error: But is my contact.php file correct? is there any php error there?

Comment: If MySQL says the file is not found, that means you haven't specified the file's pathname correctly in the `LOAD DATA` command, or that the protection on your directory or file is set up so the MySQL server software cannot find the file. So, no, your contact.php file is not yet correct. It's running, so it doesn't have syntax errors, but you haven't specified the file path correctly. For what it's worth, everybody who tries to use `LOAD DATA` goes through a hassle like this getting it to work.